# Concatenating multiple column values inside a variable by comma separated

Tags: c#, sql, linq, linq-to-sql

I have a query in `linq-to-sql` as follows:

```
var query = (from users in _context.Users 
            join consumers in _context.Consumers 
            on users.usersId equals consumers.consumerId 

            from clients in _context.Clients.Where(x => x.Id == users.Id).DefaultIfEmpty().Take(1)
            where consumerId.Contains(consumers.consumerId)
            select new UserConsumerDto 
            {
             FirstName = users.FirstName, 
             LastName = users.LastName, 
             ClientName = clients.Name
            }).ToList()
```

The above query returns me several rows; meaning that a user can have multiple clients. Therefore, I added `Take(1)` to get only one client for the time being.

Now, when I remove the `Take(1)`, several records are returned. 
I want to avoid this, by adding the client name in a single record for a user by separated comma.

For eg:

```
User 1 | ClientA, ClientB
```

Instead of:

```
User 1 | Client A
User 1 | Client B
```

Can someone please help me to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `group by` to group the records by for example `UserName` and then aggregate the client names using `string.Join(",",ClientName)` to concatenate the client names.
Here is a sample code:

```
    var userClients = from c in (dbContext joined tables)
      group c by c.UserName into u 
      select new {
          UserName = u.First().UserName,
          ClientName = string.Join(",", (from n in u select n.ClientName).ToArray()) 
      };
```

Check the sample code in this [demo](https://rextester.com/USXLK82438)

Comment: How to achieve this in `linq-to-sql` ?

Comment: @crazydev Answer was updated. Sample code and demo added.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this code

```
SELECT DISTINCT ST2.SubjectID, 
    SUBSTRING(
    (
    SELECT ','+ST1.StudentName AS [text()]
    FROM dbo.Students ST1
    WHERE ST1.SubjectID = ST2.SubjectID
    ORDER BY ST1.SubjectID
    FOR XML PATH ('')
    ), 2, 1000) [Students]
    FROM dbo.Students ST2
```

for reference [check](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/194852/how-to-concatenate-text-from-multiple-rows-into-a-single-text-string-in-sql-serv)